# Have your birthday in December,Birthday in December

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Someone was conducting a survey on people who have December Birthdays. So he said:

1.What does it feel like to have you birthday in December?
2.What does it feel like to have a December birthday?

3.What does it feel like if your birthday is in December?

What should be used:#1,#2 or #3?

Comment: Typo or mistake in #1: "you" should be "your".

Answer (score 1):

Use 'how' and not 'what.' Also, I'd omit 'like' as it does not add any value.

> How does it feel to have a birthday in December?

Or...more personalized,

> How do you feel about having your birthday in December?

In #3, you are using hypothetical condition, so, it'd be 'would.'

> How would you feel if you have your birthday in December?

'December birthday' looks down to me. It's not a good composition as compared to the rest.

Comment: Of course...remember the teacher asking "Who **have** their birthdays in January?"

Comment: "December birthday" is just fine actually, at least in American English.

Comment: @CanadianYankee if that's so, it's strange!

Comment: Type "December birthday" (with quotes) into google and you'll see lots of magazine articles, etc. that use it - 1.35 million results in all.  Maybe it's a bit of "headline speak" (using fewer words to make headlines shorter), but it sounds very natural to me.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee ,would you use: "How many people have their birthdays in December?" And of course you said that "December Birthday" sounds natural,so "who all have December Birthdays?" sounds natural, right?

Comment: @Canadian Yankee ,so would you use it?

Comment: I'd probably say, "How many people have birthdays in December" (including "their" isn't ungrammatical, but it's not necessary so I'd probably leave it out). For your second question, I don't like the construction "who all", but I could easily imagine saying, "Who here has a December birthday?"

Comment: @CanadianYankee a little piece of suggestion - searching on Google and considering it authentic, that too all results, is dangerous! :) I'm into SEO for past 7 yr. I'd probably look COCA where I found merely 2 occurrences that too strange usage again! If I am to use it, I'd probably go like - *"Celebrating a December birthday is fun as we have a festive season then."* It would be generalized statement.

Comment: “What does it feel like” is functionally equivalent to “how does it feel” - I think either construction is fine. I agree with @Canadian Yankee that “December birthday” is totally correct at least in American English. And for sentence 3 I would change it to “How would you feel if you *had* a December birthday?”

Comment: It “looks **down** to me” is not the standard English use of the word “down”.   I’d suggest that it looks “awkward”, it looks “improper” or it looks “incorrect”.

Comment: @whiskeychief I have learned that phrase from a native speaker only! Upon asking, the answer was - 'incorrect' is a bit harsh! :)

Comment: I have never heard the phrase “it looks down to me“ in American English.  Just “FYI”!